# How do I install ubuntu on a laptop without cd-rom and only usb 3 (windows 10)

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows-10, initramfs

I've tried installing with an usb-stick, and have come to the install-menu, getting the options to install or run ubuntu from usb - but no matter the choice, I end up with the error "(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system."
I've read that it often helps to change to an usb 2 port, but I don't have any.

I'm using an acer aspire V nitro
Trying to install 14.04.3 LTS on a partition.

UPDATE-
I ran ubuntu with a live CD on another PC, and restored disk image, as described in answer below. Still initramfs-error.

Comment: how have you installed ubuntu on USB  - what instructions?  Have you verified the md5sum for the ISO?

Comment: DId you disable secure boot on BIOS?

Comment: I tried -- same result. I installed it on the usb using the universal usb installer.

Comment: md5sum checks out. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I fixed this by:*

**1)** Buying an USB CD-Rom

**2)** Connecting it and booting from the live CD

**3)** Doing the regular installation and choosing install along With Windows.

*I did not get the booting from the USB to work With my PC*

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** : To be safe, download [Ubuntu 14.04.3](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) ISO again.

**Step 2** : Create a proper Ubuntu USB installation media :

Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=**  
exit
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the Ubuntu ISO and copy the content to the USB drive.

**Step 3** : Disable hibernation mode and fast startup - execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the legacy version of the **Windows Control Panel** - not the modern one.
Select **Power Settings** - enable **show hidden settings** - **uncheck fast startup**.
After having done this - **shutdown** the computer **completely** - do NOT reboot.

**Step 4** : Boot from the Ubuntu USB installation media you have created and ...

**Update addressing your response that the install media still doesn't work**

In case you have access to a an Ubuntu system, you can create the media by :
Open **Disks** and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the Ubuntu installation ISO file and the USB drive ... start restoring.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but ended up with the same initramfs-error... I used poweriso to mount the image. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Oyvach : In Windows 10 you can mount the ISO image by right-clicking the file in File Manager and select mount. Please try it again ... repeat the complete procedure of step 2 (creating the installation media). :)

Comment: @Oyvach : I updated the answer with an alternative solution to create the media properly from within Ubuntu. This way is proven to work in nearly all cases - when there is no problem with the USB drive. :)

Comment: Ok, it didn't help to do the mounting in w10, though it was easier :) I don't have any machines with ubuntu available. I tried running wubi.exe from the extracted iso, within Windows 10. And finished the installation. When rebooting, I'm asked to choose OS -- when choosing w10 everything goes as it should, but when choosing Ubuntu im prompted with a black screen "Windows task manager", saying that Windows couldn't start, referring to file "\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr" and status: "0xc000007b".

Comment: @Oyvach : It is not recommended to use Wubi as installation option since of some time ago - please read : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice - unfortunately you have to find another way to create a media. :)

Comment: @Oyvach : I have an idea - just guessing - in case Windows 10 is installed in EFI mode ... did you choose to boot the USB drive with an UEFI entry in front of the Ubuntu entry ? If not, this might be the root cause. :)

Comment: In BIOS, the choice for boot mode currently is [UEFI], and not [Legacy], if that's what you're asking..? :P The USB is listed as 1. priority for booting.

Comment: @Oyvach : Yes ... and it is important to boot the USB drive in EFI mode as well, so please select the Ubuntu entry with UEFI in front of it. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely clear on how to do this.. In the list of boot-priorities, none of the entries have UEFI in from of them. The only mention of it is under "boot mode". I assume the the usb containing the extracted ubuntu-iso is what you're aiming at with "ubuntu entry"?

Comment: @Oyvach : If there is only one entry for the Ubuntu USB installation media, you have to select this entry. :)

Comment: There is "USB HDD: SanDisk", which is the one I've been using so far. Otherwise there's the "USB CDROM:" and "USB FDD:". Should I rather use one of these?

Comment: nvm, none of them did anything :P Thanks for the suggestion, though :)

Comment: @Oyvach : As I see that you have a CD/DVD slot - burn the ISO file to a DVD and boot from USB CDROM. :)

Comment: Haha, but I don't. Do not know why it's called that, but I figure that the three slots relate to the three usb ports respectively. That would be a great fix, though :D